# Jsoup times out and cURL only works with '--compressed' header - how do I emulate this header in Jsoup?

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to use JSoup to parse content from URLs like https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/300595003

`Jsoup.connect(url).get()` simply times out, however I can access the website fine in the web browser.

Through trial and error, the simplest working curl command I found was:

```
curl 'https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/300595003' \ 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0' \ 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5' --compressed
```

I am able to translate the User-Agent and Accept-Language into JSoup, however I still get timeouts. Is there an equivalent to the `--compressed` flag for Jsoup, because the curl command will not work without it?

Answer (score 1):

To find out what `--compressed` option does try using curl with `--verbose` parameter. It will display full request headers.
Without `--compressed`:

```
> GET /groceries/en-GB/products/300595003 HTTP/2
> Host: www.tesco.com
> Accept: */*
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101
Firefox/76.0
> Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
```

With `--comppressed`:

```
> GET /groceries/en-GB/products/300595003 HTTP/2
> Host: www.tesco.com
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101
Firefox/76.0
> Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
```

The difference is new `Accept-Encoding` header so adding `.header("Accept-Encoding", "deflate, gzip")` should solve your problem.
By the way, for me both jsoup and curl are able to download page source without this header and without `--compressed` and I'm not getting timeouts, so there's a chance your requests are somehow limited by server for making too many requests.

EDIT:
It works for me using your original command with `--http1.1` so there has to be a way to make it work for you as well. I'd start with using Chrome developer tools to take a look at what headers your browser sends and try to pass all of them using `.header(...)`. You can also copy curl command to see all headers and simulate exactly what Chrome is sending:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately adding this header amongst the others didn't solve the problem for me. I have discovered that I do not need the Accept-Encoding header outside of my VPN though, so I guess they are intentionally denying these.
One other thing I notice, comparing the request being sent from Java is that it is being sent with HTTP1.1 rather than HTTP2 (which my curl is using). If I add `--http1.1` to curl, I get a 403. Will need to see if it is possible to force Java to use HTTP2...

Comment: This is what I did in the first place to generate my curl command and is usually my first step when scraping a new website. As I say, it seems to be an issue with using my VPN. With HTTP2, I am able to use my VPN. For now, I have hacked a workaround to call curl using Runtime.exec and parsing the output with JSoup.